# It does not support authentication (SMTP-AUTH) error in Thunderbird 3

Tags: email, thunderbird

My OS in `Windows 7`. I'm using `Thunderbird 3` from my home to access office mails. Though my office mail server doesn't support `POP3`, Thunderbird automagically configures itself when I provide it my email id and password. It can download emails and synchronize with server. However, I get following error when try to send a message:

> Sending of message failed. An error
>   occurred sending mail: Unable to
>   authenticate to SMTP server
>   smtp.[omitted].com. It does not
>   support authentication (SMTP-AUTH) but
>   you have chosen to use authentication.
>   Uncheck 'Use name and password' for
>   that server or contact your service
>   provider.

I didn't find anywhere from account settings dialog box a check box saying `Use name and password`. I tried disabling secure authentication by unchecking the check box `Use secure authentication` in `Server Settings` dialog box but it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea how to get rid of this problem? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/thunderbird_2_to_3_0_upgrade_unable_to_authenticate_to_smtp_server_uncheck_use_name_and_password_for_that_server

Comment: That workaround doesn't solve my company issue. But thanks for the link.

Comment: This has worked for 99% of Thunderbird users with the identical problem. Try deleting your your SMTP password.
Not enough info to help you further. Need to know your ISP, TB version, operating system, mail provider, etc
Please create a new community support topic:
http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/new
 with the info requested in our README:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Support/GetSatisfaction/README

Answer (score 1):

You could insert your own ISP's SMTP server details instead of your office's. The emails will then send. Unfortunately the emails will be more likely to be filtered as spam.

Otherwise you should ask your office helpdesk for help.